# How to use stdext::hash_set for custom type in VC++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, hashtable, containers

I want to use [`stdext::hash_set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t4xas78%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for custom type.

In fact I realized how to do so, but I am not sure if it is correcly (it is compilable, but looks somewhat dirty).

The code follows:

```
// This is my custom type
struct Point 
{
    Point(int _x, int _y, int _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}

    int x, y, z;

    bool operator< (const Point& other) const 
    {
        if (x != other.x) return x < other.x;
        if (y != other.y) return y < other.y;
        return z < other.z;
    }
};

// helper class
struct PointHashCompare {
    // value is copied from MS sources
    static const int bucket_size = 1;

    size_t operator() (const Point& p) const {
      return p.x * 31 * 31 + p.y * 31 + p.z;
    }

    bool operator() (const Point& a, const Point& b) const {
      return a < b;
    }
};
```

And declaration of variable following:

```
stdext::hash_set<Point, PointHashCompare> hSet;
```

**What does `bucket_size` in `PointHashCompare` mean?** 
Does any Microsoft documentation exist which explain `bucket_size` and suggestions to its value and why it is required at all?

(I can suppose that this is connected with the internal structure of the hash-table implementation, but different approaches can be used and they can be also changed in different VC++ versions)

I am also considering to switch to `std::unordered_set`, but now I am wondering how to manage with `stdext::hash_set`

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `stdext::hash_set`. Use `std::unordered_set` instead

Comment: I have code which already uses stdext::hash_set, seems I will end up with unsorted_set indeed. Anyway, thanks for advice.

Comment: The latter is part of the standard, so you should prefer that whenever possible. The former is a nonstandard extension. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The integer constant `bucket_size` specifies the mean number of elements
>   per "bucket" (hash-table entry) that the container should try not to
>   exceed. It must be greater than zero. The value supplied by
>   `hash_compare` is 4.

More info on page [hash_compare Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s1byw77%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)